# sum upto n terms where rth term is $r(r+1)2^r$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, telescopic-series

sum upto n terms where rth term is $r(r+1)2^r$.

> I tried to make a telescoping series but failed.It seems like i have to subtract and add something from r(r+1) such that power of 2 also change.Is there a systematic approach?

Comment: Hint (if your toolbox includes derivatives): $r(r+1)x^r=x(x^{r+1})''$.

Comment: Let $S$ be the sum. Try subtracting $S$ from $2S$ by matching powers of $2^r$. I believe this shows that the series is equal to $2 \sum r 2^r$. Can you calculate what that series is equal to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$S=\sum_{r=1}^n r(r+1)x^r$$

$$(1-x)S=2\sum_{r=1}^nrx^r-n(n+1)x^{n+1}\text{ as } r(r+1)-r(r-1)=2r$$

Again, if $$T=\sum_{r=1}^nrx^r$$

$$(1-x)T=?$$

Answer (score 2):

Take the Ansatz $\sum_{r=1}^nr(r+1)2^r=(an^2+bn+c)2^n-c$ so the $n=0$ case works, while the inductive step reduces to$$\begin{align}n(n+1)2^n&=(an^2+bn+c)2^n-(a(n-1)^2+b(n-1)+c)2^{n-1}\\&=(an^2-a(n-1)^2/2+bn-b(n-1)/2)2^n\\&=(an^2/2+(a+b/2)n+(b-a+c)/2)2^n.\end{align}$$So $a=2,\,b=-2,\,c=4$.

Comment: can you elaborate how you assumed that sum in first line?

Comment: @user69608 An [Ansatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz) is an educated guess you try for the form of a solution. In this case, it's a natural extension of $\sum_{r=1}^n2^r=2\cdot2^n-1$, which suggests if $p$ is a degree-$d$ polynomial then $\sum_{r=1}^np(r)2^r=q(n)\cdot2^n-c$ for constant $c$ and degree-$d$ polynomial $q$.

Comment: got, nice solution!

Answer (score 2):

From $$r(r+1)-2(r-1)r+(r-2)(r-1)=2$$

you can deduce

$$S_n-4S_{n-1}+4S_{n-2}
\\=\sum_{r=1}^nr(r+1)2^r -2\cdot2\sum_{r=1}^n(r-1)r2^{r-1} +2^2\sum_{r=1}^n (r-2)(r-1)2^{r-2}
\\=2\sum_{r=1}^n 2^r,$$

which is

$$S_n-4(S_n-n(n+1)2^n)+4(S_n-(n-1)n2^{n-1})=2\frac{2^{n+1}-1}2.$$

You can draw $S_n$.

Comment: can you tell the motivation behind this.  also thinking the first line for summation seems difficult to me.intuition would be very much helpful.

Comment: @user69608: the motivation is that for any polynomial $P$, the first order difference $P(n)-P(n-1)$ is one degree less; here we have a second order difference (first identity), making the degree drop from $2$ to $0$ so that we get a pure exponential. This is why we have the coefficients $1,-2,1$, which must be corrected because of the factors $2^r$, and become $1\cdot2^0,-2\cdot2^1,1\cdot2^2$. Then the shifts of the indexes, $n,n-1,n-2$ are absorbed in the summations by dropping the last terms. [Hope you can follow this summary.]